# jQuery conflict: gallery and slider

Tags: jquery, gallery, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to use an image slider with an image gallery feature on the same page.

They both call a version of jquery (fancybox.js is 1.8.2) in the following statements -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
```

I have played around with noConflict but alas I cannot get the two features to work at the same time?

Comment: Your OP should contain enough relevant code to answer the question without relying upon your demo link.  Otherwise, when the page at your link gets fixed, this question will not be helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. Your script is firing before your DOM elements are loaded (a
   result of putting your scripts in the header. This is why @powtac
   was saying to encapsulate your script in $(document).ready();)
2. Your .coinslider() function is calling before your coinslider
   script is loaded.

Try putting your scripts in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-libsans-r-b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
```

next, follow @powtac's advice:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 900, navigation: false, delay: 5000 });
});
```

That should do it.

**Edit**: based on your new source code, remove the line `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>`.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed your advice, I have re-ordered the scritp calls and added a new doc ready statement in the head. Now the images are stacked and the coinslider does not work?

Please look at my source code

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$(document).ready()` arround

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#coin-slider').coinslider({ width: 900, navigation: false, delay: 5000 });
    });
```

Comment: Thx for the quick response, I'm just finding it a little unclear to understand.

Are you saying that there should be a second document ready statement? Presently, I only have one relating to the gallery?

Comment: I have tried a second doc ready statement as above, but nothing changed.